# Different behavior between .append() and .html()

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code: https://jsfiddle.net/hbli/xyeoatf9/1/

I want to add event listener to a dynamic element:

```
$('.parent').on('mousedown', function(e){
    $('.parent').html('<div class="child"></div>');
    //$('.parent').append('<div class="child"></div>');
    console.log('parent mousedown');
})

$('body').on('click', '.child', function(e){
    console.log('child click');
})
```

If I use '`$('.parent').html('<div class="child"></div>');`', the click event never be triggered on '.child' element.
But if I change .html to .append, the event can be triggered.

I want to know why they have different behavior?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because you're using a delegated event handler on the `.child` element. Because of this the event has to propagate through the `.parent` element, so the `mousedown` event handler fires before the `.child` click.

This means that when you use `html()` the `.child` is removed, then re-created. In turn, when you use `append()` the `.child` element still exists for the delegated click event to be run on it.

Answer (score 1):

As you are overwriting the content using `html()`, the `.child` element doesn't exists anymore it is replaced thus event is not propagated.

While using `.append()` the `.child` exists and event is propagated. So you are getting the message

Answer (score 0):

adding a counter let us corroborate that click event is triggered when .child is preserved, but when it is replaced you end up with a different .child that did not initiate any event

notice how you perform mousedown on a .child and mouseup on a different one

```js
let counter = 0;
$('.parent').on('mousedown', function(e){
    ++counter;
    $('.parent').html('<div class="child">' + counter + '</div>');
    //$('.parent').append('<div class="child">' + counter + '</div>');
    console.log('parent mousedown');
})

$('body').on('click', '.child', function(e){
    console.log('child click: ' + $(this).html());
})

$('body').on('mouseup', '.child', function(e){
    console.log('child mouseup: ' + $(this).html());
})

$('body').on('mousedown', '.child', function(e){
    console.log('child mousedown: ' + $(this).html());
})
```

```css
.parent {
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
  background-color: green;
}

.child {
  width:200px;
  height:20px;
  background-color: yellow;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the method HTML and still want to add an event on the ".child" element, you can simply assign event method in the tag itself for example

```
$('.parent').on('mousedown', function(e){
    $('.parent').html('<div class="child" onclick="clickMethod();"></div>');
    console.log('parent mousedown');
})

function clickMethod()
{
    console.log('child click');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the following would be a side-by-side demo

```js
let counter1 = 0;
$('.parent-replace').on('mousedown', function(e){
    ++counter1;
    $('.parent-replace').html('<div class="child">' + counter1 + '</div>');
    console.log('parent-replace mousedown');
})

let counter2 = 0;
$('.parent-append').on('mousedown', function(e){
    ++counter2;
    $('.parent-append').append('<div class="child">' + counter2 + '</div>');
    console.log('parent-append mousedown');
})

$('body').on('click', '.child', function(e){
    console.log('child click: ' + $(this).html());
})

$('body').on('mouseup', '.child', function(e){
    console.log('child mouseup: ' + $(this).html());
})

$('body').on('mousedown', '.child', function(e){
    console.log('child mousedown: ' + $(this).html());
})
```

```css
.parent {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
}

.parent-replace {
  background-color: green;
}

.parent-append {
  background-color: blue;
}

.child {
  width:200px;
  height:20px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.side-by-side {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="side-by-side">
  REPLACING child
  <div class="parent-replace parent"></div>
</div>

<div class="side-by-side">
  APPENDING children
  <div class="parent-append parent"></div>
</div>
```